# Integer user form field with min 11 digits and max 11 digits

Tags: 7, users, entities

I need an integer form field with has a validation of **min 11 digits** and **max 11 digits.** In other words; the user has to fill in an 11 digit code.

How do i make this field and validation?

**Update:**

I managed the field by setting a min of `10000000000` and max of `99999999999`. But now i get this validation message:

> RIZIV number: the value may be no greater than 99999999999.

How do i change this validation/error message to something like:

> Fill in your right 11 digits RIZIV number.

Comment: do you need a custom validation?

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer no. Just change the error message of `field_riziv_number`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` add an integer field and set the limitations and by [hook_user_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) you can check the validation after saving the user profile.

Comment: but how do you set the limitations exactly? Its not possible i think?

Comment: when the number of digits must be 11, so the min is `10000000000` and the max is `99999999999`. right? Using this configuration no more validation is needed. Unless the zero at the beginning is allowed. In this case you need to add a `text` field and using `hook_user_update`  check for validation

Comment: i update my question. Please adjust your answer, so i can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank using string overrides module in https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides you can change all the messages of your site.

Comment: i tried this module but unfortunately its not working..?

Comment: What did you search in it?

Comment: @MeesFrenkelFrank you can also search for how to alter a message in Drupal. There are also other solutions and I gave you the most straightforward one.

Comment: ok thanks. I searched for alter, but how exactly do i change the validation error text of the `field_riziv_number` with `hook_form_alter`?

Comment: Changing the messages of Drupl is another question. Do not ask two questions in one question. You can ask that question in another separate question.